# ImageButton в GridLayout в некоторых экранах не помещается

Tags: java, android, android-studio

У меня некоторые проблемы с GridLayout ом,
в некоторых экранах кнопки расположены не равномерно, а в остальных показывает нормально, в чем причина, проблема помогите пожалуйста!

[image: здесь нормально]

[image: а здесь вот так]

и в телефонах тоже также.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrlviewcard"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".CardsFragment">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnrlayocard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:text="@string/profdisc" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridlayocard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:columnCount="2">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cardstxt"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/auto"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cardstxt"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/obrasovanie" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cardstxt"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/karaokeirasvlech" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cardstxt"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/rasnoe" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cardstxt"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/kofebary" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cardstxt"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/sferauslug" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cardstxt"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/krasotaisdorovye" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cardstxt"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/stroitelstvoiremont" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cardstxt"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/magazinyitorgovzentry" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cardstxt"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/sportiturizm" />


        </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>


    </LinearLayout>    

</ScrollView>`
```

Answer (score 2):

Причина в том, что ширина и высота у вас указаны хардкодом. А на каждом телефоне разные размеры экрана. Иногда не влазит то что вы за хардкодили.

```
android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
```

почитайте про `match_parent` и `wrap_content` и используйте эти аттрибуты что бы избежать подобных наложений.

Comment: значит надо изменить расширения изображения да, а у меня 974x529 стоит.

Comment: 974x529 очень много , думаю могут быть проблемы с производительностью. В таких случаях вам лучше использовать VectorDrawdble  или же раскладывать изображения по папкам для разных экранов. DВ любом случае использовать конкретный размер плохая практика

Answer (score 1):

Причина в том, что у ваших кнопок - фиксированная высота. Тогда как параметр веса (`app:layout_rowWeight="1"`) распределяет лишь остаток свободного места. Для различных размеров экрана кнопки будут показываться по разному в зависимости от dpi.

Как один из вариантов решения: задайте высоту = 0dp.

Возможно это "покорёжит" UI, но для того что есть пока - это лучшее решение.